# Cancel keydown event from setTimeout 0 or correct range.commonAncestorContainer in keydown

Tags: javascript, jquery, range, contenteditable, rangy

I need to get the range.commonAncestorContainer in the keydown event in order to find out if the user is inserting text or clicking inside an html element inside a contenteditable div.

Possibly that keydown event must be prevented depending on the key or current selection.

Problem: in the keydown the commonAncestorContainer is not returning the correct object. In order to get the correct object I'm using a setTimeout(..., 0) and it gives me the correct value. However, when I try to cancel the event it's already too late (?) and I'm not able to do it.

[Here is the jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/ca2s7l/e6tg80d4/3/)

```
function testTimeoutDeferred() {
    var def = $.Deferred();
    setTimeout(function() {
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        if (sel.rangeCount > 0) {
            var range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
            var parentElement = range.commonAncestorContainer;
            if (parentElement.nodeType === 3) {
                parentElement = parentElement.parentNode;
            }

            var $element = $(parentElement);

            console.log("element inside timeout with deferred - not resolved yet")
            console.log($element)

            def.resolve(true);
        }
    }, 500);
    return def.promise();
}
```

When we click in the link/type:

- test() shows the body being selected which is wrong
- testTimeout() shows the correct element being selected but the event is not canceled (code inside timeout runs after the rest)
- testTimeoutDeferred() shows the events in the correct order but still unable to cancel the keydown

How can I:

**1) cancel the event after processing the selected element?**

OR

**2) find the correct element selected in the keydown without any settimeout?**

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you are trying to do. What is exactly expected behaviour?

Comment: I'm trying to detect if the caret is inside a link or not. If it is inside a link the keydown event must be canceled. No keys allowed inside links.

Comment: something like that http://jsfiddle.net/e6tg80d4/4/ ?

Comment: Yes, thanks, that was what I was looking for. Now I'm trying to deal with the link as a block. I'm already jumping over the block with the directional keys and have the backspace working, but I'm still struggling with the delete key. Do you have any suggestions about how to detect where the caret is when the delete is pressed? At the moment it deletes each character one by one. It should delete the whole element like backspace. Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/ca2s7l/10L7rerr/5/